# Swift: case foo (let bar): without a type or assignment?

Tags: ios, swift, let

In Swift, I understand that "let" defines a constant. No problem. So "let foo = 42" and "let foo: Int" make sense. But I see several instances where simply "let foo" is written without assignment or type specification. For example "case bar (let foo): ..."

What exactly happens when "let foo" by itself is in such code?

Comment: Could you show and executable example?

Comment: Somewhere in the code there will be a case declaration like `case bar(Int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This notation is used to bind an associated value of an enumeration.

Take this for example:

```
let anOptionalInt: Int? = 15

switch (anOptionalInt) {
case .Some(let wrappedValue):
    print(wrappedValue)

case .None:
    print("the optional is nil")
}
```

This works because [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Optional_Enumeration/index.html) is an enumeration. The first expression can be written as:

```
let anOptionalInt: Optional<Int> = Optional.Some(15)
```

There are two cases: [`.Some`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Optional_Enumeration/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enumelt/Optional/s:FSq4SomeurFMGSqx_FxGSqx_) and [`.None`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Optional_Enumeration/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enumelt/Optional/s:FSq4NoneurFMGSqx_GSqx_). In the `.Some` case, there's an associated value, called `Wrapped`, whereas the `.None` case has no associated value.

In fact, `Optional.None` is the same as `nil`.